# Improve questions by reviewing them

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-page

To me it seems that some people do not take the [review feature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review) serious enough. I see several questions by new members that need serious improvements. How can this functionality be improved?

Comment: have the questions you noticed actually been listed under one of the review categories?  fairly often i see questions that could be improved, but they're neither listed for review, nor shown as having been edited.  (i don't usually check the review history separately from edit history.)  i think that only certain items are triggered automatically for review (in fact, i don't really know how the review listing is generated), so it may be possible that reviewing was never suggested, even if it would have been appropriate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: You are right. Neither I know exactly how the list is generated, but I think all first questions from new members (if they do not have 100 reputation at another page) are marked for review.

Comment: To echo what @percusse has said in his answer, We as TeX.SX are known for and proud of our friendliness.  Any 'serious' improvements that come to mind are often just the peculiarities/compulsions of one writing style reviewing another. I personally take the reviewing process pretty seriously—it is a privilege—but never do I risk offense in correcting someone unless the verbiage or formatting impedes the understanding of the question.

Answer (score 9):

Well indeed I don't take it seriously because it's not a serious feature. Some users already took away its functionality long ago and as barbara mentioned I've not seen a single new user question in the reviews since a year and some months. Probably the review system distributes the reviews to some users and locks for others to (wildly guessing here) reduce the review clashes.

I recommend editing the questions directly instead of that review system as much as you see them on the site. Nothing came good out of that system as far as I know other than light speed question closing.

Also no improvement is serious here. Because serious tone always causes trouble.